# SQL: create a view comparing different rows

Tags: sql, join, count, sql-view

I have data for movies that looks something like this:

```
cast_id | cast_name | movie_id
1         A           11
2         B           11
3         C           11
4         D           12
5         E           12
1         A           13
```

I want to create a view where I compare two different cast members so that I will start with something like this:

```
CREATE VIEW compare(cast_id_1, cast_id_2, num_movies);

SELECT * FROM compare LIMIT 1;
(1,2,2)
```

where I am looking at actor A and actor B, who have a total of 2 movies between the two of them.

Not sure how to compare the two different rows and my searchers so far have been unsuccessful. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: What is your DBMS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a self-join:

```
create view myview as 
select t1.cast_id cast_id_1, t2.cast_id cast_id_2, count(*) num_movies
from mytable t1
inner join mytable t2 on t2.movie_id = t1.movie_id and t1.cast_id < t2.cast_id
group by t1.cast_id, t2.cast_id
```

Thives generates all combinations of cast members that once appeared in the same movie, with the total number of movies. Join condition `t1.cast_id < t2.cast_id` is there to avoid "mirror" records.

You can then query the view. If you want members that have two common movies (which is actually not showing in your sample data...):

```
select * from myview where num_movies = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking a procedure might be helpful.  This stored procedure takes the 2 cast_id's and num_movies as input parameters.  It selects the movie_id's of the movies the two cast_id's have  appeared in together.  Then based on whether or not that number exceeds the num_movies parameter: either 1) a list of movies (release dates, director, etc.) is returned, else the message 'Were not in 2 movies together' is returned.

```
drop proc if exists TwoMovieActors;
go
create proc TwoMovieActors
  @cast_id_1    int,
  @cast_id_2    int,
  @num_movies   int
as
set nocount on;
declare         @m      table(movie_id      int unique not null,
                              rn            int not null);
declare         @rows   int;
with
cast_cte as (
    select *, row_number() over (partition by movie_id order by cast_name) rn
    from movie_casts mc
    where cast_id in(@cast_id_1, @cast_id_2))
insert @m
select movie_id, row_number() over (order by movie_id) rn
from cast_cte
where rn=2
select @rows=@@rowcount;

if @rows<@num_movies
    select concat('Were not in ', cast(@num_movies as varchar(11)), ' movies together');
else
    select m.movie_id, mv.movie_name, mv.release_date, mv.director
    from @m m
         join movies mv on m.movie_id=mv.movie_id;
```

To execute it would be something like

```
exec TwoMovieActors 1, 2, 2;
```